# Youtube Analytics API | averageViewPercentage

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I have a question about the YouTube Analytics API.
I would like to know how "averageViewPercentage" is calculated.

Although it is described as "The average percentage of a video watched during a video playback.", I don't what items is.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics#Watch_Time_Metrics

Comment: I would also like to know whether this metric takes into account users watching a video more than once the same way audienceWatchRatio does.